# Arc length = Integral?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Find $C^1$ function defined on a compact interval $[a,b]$ with the following property:

$$\int_a^x \sqrt{1+[f'(t)]^2}dt = \int_a^x f(t)dt $$

where  $x \in [a,b]$

I tried to do the following:
Since $f'$ is continuous, $\int_a^x \sqrt{1+[f'(t)]^2}dt$ and $\int_a^x f(t)dt $ are  differentiable. Hence we get, 
$$\sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}=f(x)$$
and 
$$ 1+[f'(x)]^2=f^2(x)$$
But I cannot proceed from here.... Can you give me any hint? Also, I am wondering finding $f$ like this does not guarantee that I find the whole set of such $f$.

Comment: You have a separable first order ordinary differential equation. Do you know the general method for solving such equations? You've shown that any such functions $f$ satisfying this arc-length property must satisfy this differential equation, so finding the general solution to this differential equation will give you all possible functions.

Comment: So $f'(x)$ should be one of the square roots of $f^2(x)-1$. We are looking at the separable DE's $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{y^2-1}$. Many ways to integrate, like $y=\cosh w$.

Answer (score 2):

As André Nicolas commented, rewriting the problem as $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{y^2-1}$$ that is to say $$dx=\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y^2-1}}$$ and changing variable $y=\cosh(z)$, $dy=\sinh(z)\,dz$ makes $dx=dz$; so $z=x+c$ and finally $y=\cosh(x+c)$.